# Cannot compile Android application in Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3

Tags: android, delphi

I've finally, after many trials and errors, managed to install what I believe all necessary files (SDK, NDK and Java) for compiling for Android on Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3. This is my first attempt at Android. I have written applications for Windows for years. Android OS is new to me. I downloaded the sample HomeProject (group) from Embarcadero and tried to compile the second and the third of the three projects in the group. I have "Android SDK 24.3.3 32bit" selected. The compilation stops immediately with this very long error message:

> [Exec Error] The command "PATH \bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\HTML5 Builder\6.0\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Kenneth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Kenneth\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.6.5.21982\bin\Firefox_Extension{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\Kenneth\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.6.6.23032\bin\Firefox_Extension{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\Kenneth\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\5.10.0.18444\bin\Firefox_Extension{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\Kenneth\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\5.10.0.18444\ucrt & "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2433_19.0.29899.2631\build-tools\27.0.3\dx.bat" --dex --output="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object Pascal\App Home Screens\Android\Release\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" " exited with code 1.

So, something exited with code 1. What? The "...dx.bat"  --dex --output="... call?

**Any ideas, anyone?**

Kenneth

Comment: I found this.. https://community.embarcadero.com/answers/can-t-compile-for-android

Answer (score 1):

run in the dos command line

> "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2433_19.0.29899.2631\build-tools\27.0.3\dx.bat"
>   --dex --output="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object
>   Pascal\App Home Screens\Android\Release\classes.dex" "c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\android-support-v4.dex.jar"
>   "c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\cloud-messaging.dex.jar"
>   "c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\fmx.dex.jar"
>   "c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar"
>   "c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-billing.dex.jar"
>   "c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-licensing.dex.jar"

and you will know the answer :) i can't post this in the comments as it's too much verbose so i post it here as a response

Answer (score 1):

Simply too many Java versions installed! Started to uninstall an older one but it broke my PC and I ended up reinstalling Windows 10 completely. Now it works.